# How to chunk a Collection of Strings in java

Tags: java, collections, chunks

I have a Collection of type String that contains anywhere from 0 to 10k values.
I am looking for an elegant or reusable way to write a method that takes in a Collection of type String and a batch size and splits the collection into smaller chunks of the provided batch size.

The best solution I could come up with is:

```
private static <T> Collection<Collection<T>> getBatches( List<T> collection, int batchSize ){
        return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < collection.size(), i -> i + batchSize)
                .mapToObj(i -> collection.subList(i, Math.min(i + batchSize, collection.size())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Some concerns:

1. I would like to take in a Collection of type String and return either a Collection of Collection of type String or a List of Collection of type String.
2. I wonder if there are any cons or edge cases that this logic will not work for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this example idea:

```
  final List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
  final int chunkSize = 3;
  final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

  final Collection<List<Integer>> result = numbers.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> 
                             counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
     .values();

  System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: @Holger will have to say something about using stateful operations like this on a stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava `Lists.partition` and tweek according to your exact requirement

> `static <T> List<List<T>> partition(List<T> list, int size)`
> Returns consecutive sublists of a list, each of the same size (the final list may be smaller).

As shown in below example

```
@Test 
public void givenList_whenParitioningIntoNSublists_thenCorrect() {
    List<Integer> intList = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    List<List<Integer>> subSets = Lists.partition(intList, 3);

    List<Integer> lastPartition = subSets.get(2);
    List<Integer> expectedLastPartition = Lists.<Integer> newArrayList(7, 8);

    assertThat(subSets.size(), equalTo(3));
    assertThat(lastPartition, equalTo(expectedLastPartition));
}
```

More details :

https://guava.dev/releases/23.3-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-

https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-split